# Http request with Json response in Java

Tags: java, json, http, connection

I want to perform a HTTP request to a Website and receive a JSON response.

But, I am not able to manage to Connect to host Page.
I tried several tutorials and tips but it won't work.

```
try{
    String thePath = "//Url";
    thePath = URLEncoder.encode(thePath, "UTF-8"); 

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(thePath);

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    System.out.println("Executing HTTP Get...\n");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200 && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed: HTTP error code: "
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

    String output = ""; Boolean keepGoing = true;
    while(keepGoing){
        String currentLine = br.readLine();

        if(currentLine == null)
            keepGoing = false;
        else
            output += currentLine;
    }

    System.out.println("Raw string result: \n" + output);

} catch (MalformedURLException e){
    System.out.println("Caught MalformedURLException: " + e.toString());

} catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println("Caught IOException: " + e.toString());

} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Caught Exception: " + e.toString());
}
```

Caught Exception: java.lang.IllegalargumentException: Host name may not be null

Comment: What did you try? What errors are you getting? etc etc.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What is the problem/exception/unexpected behavior?

Comment: I tried Serveral HttpGet tutorials :/ Everytime I try to connect he instantly crashed and got Exceptions for not vailid Hostname. i never got past that point. I tried the link I use in my browser and it works perfektly

Comment: @user2814223, post the code. otherwise how do we know the issue

Answer (score 0):

Remove outermost try/catch block, let exception print stack trace. Then look at the methods on top of stack, find the line number in your code which makes wrong method call. Learn documentation on that method and provide correct arguments. Most likely, you provide bad URL.